# FQL - Getting Facebook user Album Covers and number of pictures

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-fql

Is it possible to get all user Album Covers + the Number of pictures for each album?

I can get User Album Covers by:

```
SELECT aid, pid, src_small, src, src_big FROM photo WHERE aid IN(SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me()
```

.

but I want to get also **how many pictures** in each album....

I can run a Loop all user albums, and for each album run another FQL, but I wander if there is a better way of doing it faster/more efficient

Any suggestion?

Thanks, 
Gtamir

Answer (score 1):

```
    function getAlbum() {
FB.api('/me/albums', function(resp) {
    console.log('Albums', resp);
    var ul = document.getElementById('albums');
    for (var i=0, l=resp.data.length; i<l; i++) {
      var
        album = resp.data[i],
        li = document.createElement('li'),
        span = document.createElement('span'),
        a = document.createElement('a');

      a.innerHTML = album.name;
       span.innerHTML = album.count;
      li.appendChild(a);
      li.appendChild(span);
      ul.appendChild(li);
    }
  });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

number of pic in each album is available in "album" table's "photo_count" property, since you require photo information from "photo" table, and FQL does not support joining tables, your only catch is to use multiquery

```
$multiQuery = {
 "query1":"SELECT aid,owner,name,photo_count,type,object_id FROM album WHERE owner IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = me())",
 "query2":"SELECT aid, pid, src_small, src, src_big FROM photo WHERE aid IN(SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=me())"
 };

$param = array(       
 'method' => 'fql.multiquery',       
 'queries' => $multiQuery,       
 'callback' => '');

$queryresults = $facebook->api($param);
```

I haven't tested the code personally, but it should go something like that